# How do I get from orthographic to perspective?

Tags: java, 3d, rendering, perspective

I programmed a cube in java and calculated the x y and z position for it's rotation on the x,y and z axis but I'm finding it hard to display the z axis i've been trying to change the distance of the vectors with higher z values to be closer to the middle of the Screen or the (0,0) point but am finding this rather hard any tips?
Thank you.

here's the code:

```
public class vert {
 //screen position
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;
 //real rot position
 int xr;
 int yr;
 int zr;

 public void rotate(int xpos,int ypos,int zpos,int rotx,int roty,int rotz) {

    //x,y
    //calculate the new rotation 
    double rx1 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(ypos,xpos)) + rotx;
    //calculate the hypotenuse
    double hypx1 = Math.sqrt(xpos * xpos + ypos * ypos);
    //calculate x1 
    double posx1 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rx1)) * hypx1;
    int tointx1 = (int) Math.round(posx1);
    int x1 = tointx1;
    //calculate y1
    double posy1 = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rx1)) * hypx1;
    int tointy1 = (int) Math.rint(posy1);
    int y1 = tointy1;

    //x,z
    //calculate the new rotation 
    double ry2 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(zpos,x1)) + roty;
    //calculate the hypotenuse
    double hypy2 = Math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + zpos * zpos);
    //calculate x final
    double posx2 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(ry2)) * hypy2;
    int tointx2 = (int) Math.round(posx2);
    int x2 = tointx2;
        //calculate z1
    double posz2 = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(ry2)) * hypy2;
    int tointz2 = (int) Math.rint(posz2);
    int z1 = tointz2;

    //y,z
    //calculate the new rotation 
    double rz3 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(z1,y1)) + rotz;
    //calculate the hypotenuse
    double hypz3 = Math.sqrt(y1 * y1 + z1 * z1);
    //calculate y final
    double posy3 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rz3)) * hypz3;   
    int tointy3 = (int) Math.round(posy3);  
    int y2 = tointy3;
    //calculate z final
    double posz3 = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rz3)) * hypz3;   
    int tointz3 = (int) Math.rint(posz3);   
    int z2 = tointz3; 

    xr = x2;
    yr = y2;
    zr = z2 + 128;
 }

 public void perspective() {

    double pers = Screen.camfocallenght / zr;
    x = (int) Math.rint(xr * pers) + Screen.x;
    y = (int) Math.rint(yr * pers) + Screen.y;
 }
}
```

And here's the code that draws the cube onto screen:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen extends JComponent{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

static int height = 400;
static int width = 600;

static double camfocallenght = 100;

static int y = height / 2;
static int x = width / 2;

int movex = 0;
int movey = 0;
int movez = -100;

int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;

vert[] v = new vert[12];

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    v[0] = new vert();
    v[0].rotate(movex + 45,movey + -45,movez + 45, a, b, c);
    v[1] = new vert();
    v[1].rotate(movex + 45,movey + 45,movez + 45, a, b, c);
    v[2] = new vert();
    v[2].rotate(movex + -45,movey + 45,movez + 45, a, b, c);
    v[3] = new vert(); 
    v[3].rotate(movex + -45,movey + -45,movez + 45, a, b, c);

    v[4] = new vert();
    v[4].rotate(movex + 45,movey + -45,movez + -45, a, b, c);
    v[5] = new vert();
    v[5].rotate(movex + 45,movey + 45,movez + -45, a, b, c);
    v[6] = new vert();
    v[6].rotate(movex + -45,movey + 45,movez + -45, a, b, c);
    v[7] = new vert();
    v[7].rotate(movex + -45,movey + -45,movez + -45, a, b, c);

    v[0].perspective();
    v[1].perspective();
    v[2].perspective();
    v[3].perspective();
    v[4].perspective();
    v[5].perspective();
    v[6].perspective();
    v[7].perspective();

    g.setColor(Color.green);

    g.drawLine( v[4].x, v[4].y, v[5].x, v[5].y);
    g.drawLine( v[6].x, v[6].y, v[7].x, v[7].y);
    g.drawLine( v[5].x, v[5].y, v[6].x, v[6].y);
    g.drawLine( v[7].x, v[7].y, v[4].x, v[4].y);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);

    g.drawLine(v[0].x, v[0].y, v[4].x, v[4].y);
    g.drawLine(v[1].x, v[1].y, v[5].x, v[5].y);
    g.drawLine(v[2].x, v[2].y, v[6].x, v[6].y);
    g.drawLine(v[3].x, v[3].y, v[7].x, v[7].y);

    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);

    g.drawLine( v[0].x, v[0].y, v[1].x, v[1].y);
    g.drawLine( v[2].x, v[2].y, v[3].x, v[3].y);
    g.drawLine( v[1].x, v[1].y, v[2].x, v[2].y);
    g.drawLine( v[3].x, v[3].y, v[0].x, v[0].y);

    String ShowZ = Integer.toString(v[1].xr);
    String Show4 = Integer.toString(v[4].x);
    String Showb = Integer.toString(b);

    g.drawString("x rotation:", 0, 10);
    g.drawString(Showb, 0, 22);
    g.drawString("z pos of vert 1:", 0, 30);
    g.drawString(ShowZ, 0, 42);
    g.drawString("x pos of vert 1 with perspective:", 0, 50);
    g.drawString(Show4, 0, 62);

    //a++;
    b++;
    //c++;

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Line");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Screen());
    while (true) {
        frame.getContentPane().repaint();
    }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Ok,here's the graphics

Comment: I Guess no help in sight :(

Comment: I recommend starting here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Comment: (And using matricies - It will make your math a lot cleaner)

Comment: so I've been playing around with this but still couldn't get it to work any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to divide the x and y components by z. If you want to put the vanishing point "farther", then make the z component smaller (e.g. divide it by a constant). If you want to make the fov larger, then increase it by a constant.

Comment: Thanks tried that but got this as result: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException

Comment: @ENR813 That clearly states what the problem is. Make sure you don't divide by zero

Comment: the Cube collapsed into a plane with an x dont know why

Comment: @ENR how large can the z componebt be?

Comment: I don't seem to be calculating the z component incorrectly

Comment: no the z component can be at largest 128

Comment: @ENR813 Try normalizing z

Answer (score 1):

You will get a lot more of readability if you use matrices for this, then to find the new position of the vector, you just multiply the vector by the matrix.

This question is a bit old, but if you meant how to find the on-screen position based on the world position, then you need to multiply the world position by the [perspective matrix](https://github.com/ferreiradaselva/mathc/blob/8f5b3e304121f9db2e8b5ae16f1e409c98809865/mathc.c#L3287):

```
mat4 perspective = mat4_perspective_fov(fov, width, height, near, far);
onscreen_pos = vec4_multiply_mat4(world_pos, perspective);
```

If you meant how to make a transition from [orthographic](https://github.com/ferreiradaselva/mathc/blob/8f5b3e304121f9db2e8b5ae16f1e409c98809865/mathc.c#L3244) to perspective (and vice-versa), you can linear interpolate two projection matrices:

```
mat4 perspective = mat4_perspective_fov(fov, width, height, near, far);
mat4 orthographic = mat4_ortho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
mat4 interpolated = mat4_lerp(perspective, ortho, 0.5);
onscreen_pos = vec4_multiply_mat4(world_pos, interpolated);
```

Then you will have a middle ground (`0.5`) between an orthographic and perspective projection.